# Kill Counter Doesn't Count Being Thrown Into The Void

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

So I am making a Knock Back PvP server, and for some reason my scoreboard for kill count doesn't go up when you get hit into the void.

Comment: What are your commands? We can't help you if you don't tell us what you're doing.

Comment: I have a scoreboard set up that is playerKillCount, and is displayed to the sidebar. That is all I have.

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out, they were being knocked into the void, they had to die from fall damage for it to count. Problem Solved :D